# Creation of presentation in the shell teminal using Pandoc

Tags: bash, powerpoint, presentation

I am looking for an automatic way to create power point presentation from the ensemble of input PNG pictures located in the same folder, following the simple algorithm executed from Linix / Mac OSX terminal with Bash:

```
for img in input_folder/*.png; do
some command to add $img to the new page >> ./presentation.pptx 
done
```

I have tried to use Pandoc

```
pandoc -f png -s *.png -t pptx -o presentation.pptx
```

but the software did not recognize input format. Would it be possible to integrate it into my workflow to post-process images quickly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `pandoc` document and embed the images there.

```
ls *jpg | sed 's/^/![caption](/;s/$/)\n/' > file
pandoc file  -t pptx -o presentation.ppt
```

If you're going to use it in a script, you'll need a more robust way to create the `pandoc` file. Processing the output of `ls` may be ok for a quick check, but not for serious scripting.

Comment: it works but I get this warning on the second step from pandoc: [WARNING] Could not deduce format from file extension. Defaulting to markdown . Then I tried to open the ppt file with openffice and it tells me that the file is corrupted and inside there is only one page with the first IMAGE ... then I tested it with the creation of PDF and it l contains all inserted images .

Comment: ah yes, there needs to be a blank line after each image. Added the `\n` in the `sed`.

Comment: still does not work since it just adds "n" in the end of each string

Comment: Are you sure you put in the backslash (`\n`)?

Comment: yep just coppied it from your answer. It may be the issue since I uses macOSX ..

Comment: SO FINALLY it works :-) I created the script in this way: for f in "$blocks"/*.png; do
   printf '![caption](%s)\n\n' "$f"; done

Comment: BTW the open office still tells that there is a problems with file although it can be readed